# PHP date_format + date_create VS date + strtotime

Tags: php

As in programming there are so many ways to achieve the same goal I often find myself wondering about the best one.
Tried to find an answer to this one on the web but no one seems to wonder about it. So maybe stupid question?
Anyway, here goes:

Assuming that *$date* is in the format yyyy/mm/dd
Is there any particular reason to chose one of this two approaches rather than the other to change the format?

A) date_format(date_create($date), 'd-m-Y')

B) date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date))

I mean, both works well, but is there some kind of, I don't know,  speed, precision, compatibility or anything else that makes one better than the other?

Thanks

Comment: The first method is part of a more general replacement for the original date functions. It's object-oriented with `DateTime` objects that you can manipulate, rather than just using numeric timestamps.

Comment: But if all you want to do is format a specific date, the old way in (B) is fine.

Comment: Oooh, I see! I didn't thought of the Object - Timestamp difference. Thanks^^